# Yii Restful API will create on POST but not populate any variables

Tags: json, api, rest, post, yii

Hello I am currently trying to use POSTMAN to test an early API that is based of of this post
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/

I am having an error when trying to either submit variables via POST in php url style or even sending an object. The response from the API comes back 200 and it creates a new entry into the database, but unfortunately it will not take any info from the post variables or jason object, it just comes up null. It seems now that that code is just looking through $_POST variables to and trying to match them to a model variable and if so, it should update it save it, However when i try to send through url parameters in POSTMAN or even change content type json and send raw json object I seem to have no luck with it.

Also I really only need it to decode a jason object and not post parameters so maybe that is where I will start by removing the $post loop and working on retrieving a JSON object instead. Thanks for any help!

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    switch($_GET['model'])
    {
        // Get an instance of the respective model
        case 'event':
            $model = new Event;                    
            break; 
        case 'media':
            $model = new Media;                    
            break; 
        case 'comment':
            $model = new Comment;                    
            break;
        default:
            $this->_sendResponse(501, 
                sprintf('Mode <b>create</b> is not implemented for model <b>%s</b>',
                $_GET['model']) );
                Yii::app()->end();
    }
    // Try to assign POST values to attributes
    foreach($_POST as $var=>$value) {
        // Does the model have this attribute? If not raise an error
        if($model->hasAttribute($var))
            $model->$var = $value;
        else
            $this->_sendResponse(500, 
                sprintf('Parameter <b>%s</b> is not allowed for model <b>%s</b>', $var,
                $_GET['model']) );
    }
    // Try to save the model
    if($model->save())
        $this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($model));
    else {
        // Errors occurred
        $msg = "<h1>Error</h1>";
        $msg .= sprintf("Couldn't create model <b>%s</b>", $_GET['model']);
        $msg .= "<ul>";
        foreach($model->errors as $attribute=>$attr_errors) {
            $msg .= "<li>Attribute: $attribute</li>";
            $msg .= "<ul>";
            foreach($attr_errors as $attr_error)
                $msg .= "<li>$attr_error</li>";
            $msg .= "</ul>";
        }
        $msg .= "</ul>";
        $this->_sendResponse(500, $msg );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by removing $POST loop and changing to a JSON object scheme only. Here is the code if anyone happens to find themselves in this situation.

```
//read the post input (use this technique if you have no post variable name):
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");

//decode json post input as php array:
$data = CJSON::decode($post, true);

//load json data into model:
$model->attributes = $data;
```

Used that instead of the foreach loop through $_POST variables. Now it accepts a json object instead. Happy Coding all!

Comment: I am facing same problem as you were facing, going to try your answer today. It will be good for other users if you accept your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm not sure what your problem is. If you can see the values POSTed in `$_POST` but not assigned to `$model`, it's probably because you did not specify the validation rules for those fields in the model. If you do not need to validate the fields, simply mark them as `'safe'` in the model's `rules()` function like below.

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('fieldName1,fieldName2', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

Comment: my gii automatically generates those so thats not the issue but thanks for the input I acutally fixed it myself and I am posting the answer